# Detecting browser type after login in django

Tags: django

I've only been working with django for 6 months, and I'm not really clear on the flow of the login process.

I have a client that has a customized login screen created by a template. It has a submit button with:

In their urls file they have:

(r'^accounts/login/$', login)

In their views file they call login(request)

What they want is, after the user has successfully logged in, I need to detect which browser they are using, and depending on which it is, potentially pop up a dialog box. I can't figure out where that code would live. I'm not asking how to detect the browser type, but rather, where that javascript code would go, and how I would cause it to get invoked after the login.

I could detect the browser type in the login screen and pass that back to the server, but then how would I give control back to the browser after the login if I do need to pop up the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login-view use the [request-object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) to get the browser type.

You could create your own [login-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) or manipulate (you should not do this - but it is posible) the django-default.

Comment: I know how to get the browser type. But this is all server side. I need to how to transfer control back to the browser to display the pop up.

Comment: you could add a var to your response...something like "popup": 1 and check it in the template. If it is set you could create your popup with jQuery. (just the quick and dirty style)

Comment: Call login, it returns, I check the browser type, see that I need to display the pop up. Here's where I'm not sure what to do next. I don't want to disrupt the existing flow - currently at this point the user is in the app - after they dismiss the pop up it needs to at the that same point.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the variable to the response. After the successful login, the code calls HttpResponseRedirect. How can I can I add a variable to that?

Comment: hmm, you can't add vars to redirect. You could try a workaround and add a session-cookie with the popup-information. You can access session-data within your template.

Comment: Thank you very much, This has gotten me very close. I can now communicate the needed status to the base template, but the issue I am having now is that they want the popup to be on top of the login screen, and it's displaying on a blank screen, after the login screen is cleared.

Comment: So it would appear there is no way to send data from django to the browser that updates the page without first clearing it. Is that true?

Comment: yes, that's true. you could add the form-data into the session-cookie...but man, that isn't secure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should check request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].You can act depending on this string, but be aware that browser info can be changed.

Probably write your own template context processor which will populate all the templates and set class='firefox-12' to a body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are trying to do will have to be done with Django and with HTML. You will customize your login, pick up the browser type in there and then use it inside the template to display the pop-up you need, based on the results you just collected. Django documentation will help you with the template code, since it has plenty examples that will help you with this. And it has many more examples that shows how to make Django interact with the browser, but of course, limited to HTML, CSS, Javascript, Jquery code.